# Did the Vanderbilts from the Gilded Age bathe in saltwater?

Tags: united-states, water, superstition

Recently, I visited the mansion that the Vanderbilt family (from the Gilded Age, late 1800s) used to live in -- it's commonly referred to as "The Breakers", located in Newport, Rhode Island.  Many of the bathrooms had bathtubs with four valves: two valves for regular water, and another two for saltwater, supposedly.

The lady giving us the tour of the mansion claimed that the Vanderbilts bathed in saltwater, believing that doing so was beneficial for their skin.

Is this true?  Did the Vanderbilts bathe in saltwater?

[image]

Comment: Is there are a reason why you're skeptical? The ocean is like a 100m away from their house, seems pretty reasonable. I also doubt this is a notable claim.

Comment: If the tour guide believes it it is notable enough. A bigger question is, why should anyone NOT believe the claim?

Comment: You can go to a "spa" today and get a saltwater bath.  Why would it not have been possible 100 years ago?

Comment: Having sea water piped to a home is obviously possible, but it definitely seems a bit unusual; just that I'd say it's valid to question.